# Spring Boot OAuth2 with custom security filter

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have a spring boot setup with an OAuth2 authorization and resource server. The user is able to acquire tokens by making a POST request to `/oauth/token`. So far, so good.

However, I don't want to protect `/oauth/token` via BASIC auth but by means of a custom security filter.

I tried the following but `DemoAuthenticationFilter` is never called:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // ...
        http.addFilterBefore(new DemoAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token").authenticated();
    }
}
```

Also, if I try to add it to `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` the filter is only called *after* the request is authenticated via OAuth2:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       // ...
       http.addFilterBefore(new DemoAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
       http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/token").authenticated();
    }
}
```

Some simple example how to achieve this would be really helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServer extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
        oauthServer.allowFormAuthenticationForClients().addTokenEndpointAuthenticationFilter(new AligenieFilter());
    }

    //....
}
```

It works for me.